# Flash problem in Firefox Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium

I have flash problem on YouTube and other flash sites in Firefox,
but all seems to work fine in Chromium.

Here are the screenshots:

[image: firefox]

[image: chromium]

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Does the problem occur if you watch the video in Firefox in another user account? (I'm talking about user accounts on your Ubuntu system, not YouTube user accounts.) If you only have one account, you can create a second account for testing purposes. (Please note that I am not suggesting that this is an acceptable workaround--I'm asking you to try it because this provides diagnostic information important to determining the cause of the problem.) You can post your answer to this question as a comment or, preferably, edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue after the last upgrade to Firefox 8 and the last update of flash. Firefox didn't behave properly in case of any website with flash, while Google Chrome had not such issues.

I could solve the issue by installing the [FlashAid add-on from here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/) and selecting the Chrome Flash Player rather than the Adobe one.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This add-on is no longer available now. When accessing the link, we see the following message: "This add-on has been removed by its author. "

Comment: @CristianaNicolae nor is Firefox 8 .. the question is from nov. 17, 2011 !!

Comment: @SorenA - ...And by doing this, I've updated its information. ;-) Ideally, AskUbuntu pages are always up-to-date. And, on the other hand, I wonder how many people know what version is their browser? I bet that many of the ones reading our lines here realize for the first time that their Firefox must be way above 8, and they're heading to the "About" section to see exactly how "old" is their browser. These are tiny things that people don't give much attention too. The truth is that we care to know our app version only when that app stops working properly.